# Searching in a list of objects containing dates

Tags: java, list, search

Suppose I have a list of messages `List<Message> conversation` that have a `Date` field.

```
public class Message {
    private Date time;
    ...
}
```

And I want to find all messages within a timespan, delimited by two `Date` objects, `fromDate` and `toDate`:

```
public List<Message> getMessagesInRange(final Date fromDate, final Date toDate, final List<Message> conversation) {
    List<Message> messagesInRange = new ArrayList<Message>();
    ...
    return messagesInRange;
}
```

The list of messages is sorted by time (older messages were added before newer ones). Now, I could iterate through the entirety of the list from the beginning and populate `messagesInRange` adding all of the messages that are within the range specified. Once I reach a more recent date than `toDate`, I could end the iteration since I know the list is sorted.

But maybe there are no messages within the specified range, and iterating from the beginning was a waste of time. I'd like to know of an efficient way of getting a reference to the first message in the list that is within the range, and iterate from there. Perhaps this can be done with a binary search?

Comment: @yts there can be situation when collection does not have *exact* match, but sub-range is not empty.

Comment: @ursa actually, the comparator method does work, because the negative index returned can be used to find the Message with the date next to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- implement messages comparator;
- use SortedSet to store sorted structure of your messages.

Java code:

```
MessageComparator messageComparator = new MessageComparator();
SortedSet<Message> allMessages = new TreeSet<>(messageComparator);

public List<Message> getMessagesInRange(final Date fromDate, final Date toDate, final List<Message> conversation) {
    return new ArrayList<Message>(allMessages.subSet(
        messageComparator.minFrom(fromDate), true,  messageComparator.maxFrom(toDate), true).values());
}
```

Implementation examples:

```
public class Message {
    private static final AtomicLong ID_COUNTER = new AtomicLong();
    private final long timestamp;
    private final String text;
    private final long id;

    public Message(Date time, String text) {
        this(time, text, ID_COUNTER.incrementAndGet());
    }

    private Message(Date time, String text, long id) {
        this.timestamp = time.getTime(); // (a) Date is mutable & (b) better memory consumption
        this.text = text == null ? "" : text;
        this.id = id;
    }

    ... // getters & logic (if any)

    // Keep in mind - equals & compareTo should be in sync.
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (null == obj) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!obj.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        Message that = (Message) obj;
        return timestamp == that.timestamp && id == that.id && message.equals(that.message);
    }
}

public class MessageComparator implements Comparator<Message> {
    // Keep in mind - equals & compareTo should be in sync.
    public int compare(Message m1, Message m2) {
        if (m1 == null ? m2 == null : m1.equals(m2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (m1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (m2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        int c = Long.compare(m1.timestamp, m2.timestamp);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
        c = m1.text.compareTo(m2.text);
        if (c != 0) {
            return c;
        }
        c = Long.compare(m1.id, m2.id);
        return c;
    }

    public Message minFrom(Date date) {
        return new Message(new Date(date.getTime()), null, -1);
    }

    public Message maxFrom(Date date) {
        return new Message(new Date(date.getTime() + 1), null, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be fine except I can't use a SortedMap to store my messages, since two messages may have the EXACT same Date and the keys in a Map have to be unique.

Comment: And what is the problem? You can use their IDs as the last step in comparison. Lazy UUID or long id = CNT.incrementAndGet()

Comment: I am not sure I understand. How does a UUID solve this? I still can't use Date as key to SortedMap since when populating the map two Messages may have the exact same Date and the newer one would overwrite the older one.

Comment: This is excellent. You really thought about everything, even concurrency. Why do you suggest storing the Date as an int timestamp? I need to print dates in a readable format and there is no getter for Date in class Message, so its value won't be modified.

Comment: why 'Date vs long'? On x64 bit JVM Date requires > 100 bytes, while long = exact 8 bytes. when you work with highload ~10^8 messages per minute you should think on such staff. if it is not the case for you - you are free to use Date objects =)

Comment: This is quite long, but this is what I am looking for.